# Plotting a histogram from pre-counted data in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'd like to use Matplotlib to plot a histogram over data that's been pre-counted.  For example, say I have the raw data

```
data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 10]
```

Given this data, I can use

```
pylab.hist(data, bins=[...])
```

to plot a histogram.

In my case, the data has been pre-counted and is represented as a dictionary:

```
counted_data = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 4, 6: 1, 10: 1}
```

Ideally, I'd like to pass this pre-counted data to a histogram function that lets me control the bin widths, plot range, etc, as if I had passed it the raw data.  As a workaround, I'm expanding my counts into the raw data:

```
data = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(value, count)
            for (value, count) in counted_data.iteritems()))
```

This is inefficient when `counted_data` contains counts for millions of data points.

Is there an easier way to use Matplotlib to produce a histogram from my pre-counted data?

Alternatively, if it's easiest to just bar-plot data that's been pre-binned, is there a convenience method to "roll-up" my per-item counts into binned counts?

Comment: As a sidenote: To expand your counts into raw data, you could also use the `Counter` class and its elements() method :

`from collections import Counter`  

`c = Counter(counted_data)`  
`data = list(c.elements())`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I used [pyplot.hist](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist)'s `weights` option to weight each key by its value, producing the histogram that I wanted:

`pylab.hist(counted_data.keys(), weights=counted_data.values(), bins=range(50))`

This allows me to rely on `hist` to re-bin my data.

Comment: and your way of getting the data out makes more sense than mine.  It's fine with me if you accept your own answer.

Comment: This was the clue I needed. In my case I have a list of counts, and bin ranges: `plt.hist(bins, bins=len(bins), weights=counts)` was the invocation I needed

Comment: Word of warning: I have noticed that this gives incorrect result if bins have different size, and `density=True` is used. Probably not a bug, rather a mathematical difference between pdf and cdf.

Answer (score 34):

You can use the `weights` keyword argument to `np.histgram` (which `plt.hist` calls underneath)

```
val, weight = zip(*[(k, v) for k,v in counted_data.items()])
plt.hist(val, weights=weight)
```

Assuming you *only* have integers as the keys,  you can also use `bar` directly:

```
min_bin = np.min(counted_data.keys())
max_bin = np.max(counted_data.keys())

bins = np.arange(min_bin, max_bin + 1)
vals = np.zeros(max_bin - min_bin + 1)

for k,v in counted_data.items():
    vals[k - min_bin] = v

plt.bar(bins, vals, ...)
```

where ... is what ever arguments you want to pass to `bar`  [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar)

If you want to re-bin your data see [Histogram with separate list denoting frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001167/histogram-with-separate-list-denoting-frequency/19006231#19006231)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the `weights` option; I had overlooked it, but it solves my problem perfectly (see my answer).

Comment: I hadn't made that connection (got blinded by directly using `bar`). Edited to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use seaborn to plot the histogram :

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.distplot(
    list(
        counted_data.keys()
    ), 
    hist_kws={
        "weights": list(counted_data.values())
    }
)
```

Answer (score 4):

the length of the "bins" array should be longer than the length of "counts". Here's the way to fully reconstruct the histogram:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
bins = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]).astype(float)
counts = np.array([5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3, 7]).astype(float)
centroids = (bins[1:] + bins[:-1]) / 2
counts_, bins_, _ = plt.hist(centroids, bins=len(counts),
                             weights=counts, range=(min(bins), max(bins)))
plt.show()
assert np.allclose(bins_, bins)
assert np.allclose(counts_, counts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to tacaswell's comment, `plt.bar` can be much more efficient than `plt.hist` here for large numbers of bins (>1e4). Especially for a crowded random plot where you only need plot the highest bars because the width required to see them will cover most of their neighbors anyway. You can pick out the highest bars and plot them with

```
i, = np.where(vals > min_height)
plt.bar(i,vals[i],width=len(bins)//50)
```

Other statistical trends may prefer to instead plot every 100th bar or something similar.

The trick here is that `plt.hist` wants to plot all of your bins whereas `plt.bar` will let you just plot the sparser set of visible bins.

Answer (score 0):

`hist` uses `bar` under the hood, this will produce something similar to what `hist` creates (assumes bins of equal size):

```py
bins = [1,2,3]
heights = [10,20,30]

ax = plt.gca()
ax.bar(bins, heights, align='center', width=bins[-1] - bins[-2])
```